# Android SAX implementation can't throw exception

Tags: java, android, saxparser

I'm using Android SAX parser which allows to bind listeners to EndTextElementListener event, however the listeners provided by Android don't allows us to throw exceptions, so for example how do i stop the parser during the process ?

Some code:

```
item.getChild("child").setEndTextElementListener( new EndTextElementListener() {
        @Override
        public void end(String s) {

            if( expression )
                throw new CustomException(); //Can't do this because end method don't throw SaxExceptions

        }
    });
```

CustomException extends SaxException by the way. But the listeners don't throw SaxExceptions so is there any way of doing it ? Or switching to a pull parser is the only option ?

Comment: Are you saying that the compiler won't allow you to throw an exception?  How about throwing an unchecked exception, i.e. a sub-class of RuntimeException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about exactly what type of exception is thrown, then throw a sub-class of RuntimeException.  The compiler will allow this.

```
if( expression )
    throw new MyCustomException();
}
```

where:

```
class MyCustomException extends RuntimeException ...
```